# Serialization of complex classes in Hazelcast

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a class(A) which contains both primitive data types and non-primitive data types. I also have lists of objects such as List obj where XYZ is some other class. When I instantiate and do a get on a map I get

com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize A error. How can I resolve it.

```
@Entity(value = "A", noClassnameStored = true)
public class A implements Serializable
{
@Id
private String p;
private String jrr;
private String ring;
private List<Signature> sam;
private String noth; 
private List<GroupRole> got;
private List<String> lost;
private List<String> folders;
public List<FolderDef> folders;
private List<ViewConfig> views;
private List<FavoriteContact> favorites;
private String crtBy;
private Date crtDate;
private String modBy;
private Date modDate;
private Boolean active;
private List<Preference> preferences;

private List<nah> chet;

private List<yup> ellis;

private Boolean pp;

private Boolean oo;

private String cc;
private String aa;
private String bb;

private String tt;
private String uu;
private String dd;
private String xx;
private String ii;
private Boolean zz;

private String x;

private byte[] y;

private Boolean z;

}
```

there are getters and setters method as well I am ignoring that

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.pck.ckg.nus.ver.hazelcast.'
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:161)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:122)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.DataRecordFactory.newRecord(DataRecordFactory.java:44)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractRecordStore.createRecord(AbstractRecordStore.java:96)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.createRecord(DefaultRecordStore.java:74)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.loadRecordOrNull(DefaultRecordStore.java:435)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.get(DefaultRecordStore.java:636)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation.run(GetOperation.java:41)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:194)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:406)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:433)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:569)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:554)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:513)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:207)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:60)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:67)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:103)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:154)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:127)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:243)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.execute(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:78)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.unblock(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:239)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.andThen(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:215)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:69)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:103)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:154)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:96)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:33)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:155)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(ClientProxy.java:225)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:219)
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.getInternal(ClientMapProxy.java:303)
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:297)
at com.citi.icg.xsc.server.hazelcast.Client.main(Client.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: 
com.pck.csk.kxp.dd.srh.[some class which is being used in A]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:111)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:104)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:158)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:122)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.DataRecordFactory.newRecord(DataRecordFactory.java:44)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractRecordStore.createRecord(AbstractRecordStore.java:96)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.createRecord(DefaultRecordStore.java:74)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.loadRecordOrNull(DefaultRecordStore.java:435)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.get(DefaultRecordStore.java:636)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation.run(GetOperation.java:41)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:194)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:406)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:433)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:569)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:554)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:513)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:207)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:60)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:67)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:103)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:154)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
```

Comment: Can you please share your entity classes? And also can you please add the full stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding implements Serializable to all the nested classes as well as class A

Answer (score 0):

All nested classes needs to be serializable . To debug SerializationException and determine which attribute is not Serializable  you can enable extended debug option in java by setting

**-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true**